# Dataframe: Divide each group by a vector corresponding to each group in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I have a data frame like this:

```
df1 <- structure(list(user_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), param_a = c(123, 
2.3, -9, 1, -0.03333, 4, -41, -12, 0.89)), .Names = c("user_id", 
"param_a"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

and another `dataframe` of vectors:

```
df2 <- structure(list(user_id = c(1, 2, 3), param_b = c(34, 12, -0.89
)), .Names = c("user_id", "param_b"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now I want to divide each group in `df1` by corresponding value in `df2`:

For example for a group of user 1 divide each row by `param_b` first vector:

```
    user_id param_a
    1       123/34 
    1       2.3/34 
    1      -9/34
    2       1/12
    2      -0.03333/12
    2       4/12
....
```

for user 2 divide each row by `param_b` second vector.

Please advise how can I divide a grouped by user `dataframe` by a vector per each group?

P.S

If I have df1 extended to param_a, param_k, param_p

and df2 extended accordingly with param_b, param_l, param_r

How can I perform this kind of operation? @nicola suggested a very nice solution but I want to extend it.

Comment: Try `df1$param_a/df2$param_b[match(df1$user_id,df2$user_id)]`.

Comment: @nicola it doens't work

Comment: @nicola, if I have param_a, param_k, param_p and param b is a vector of multiple numbers it doesn't work.

Comment: It works on your example. You should state why it doesn't work and provide a better example. FWIW, these kinds of "it doesn't work", without nothing else are so frustrating and let me question why I'm still here on this site trying to help others.

Comment: @nicola, I am sorry. You are completely right. I just thought it's a generic way to do this, but when I did apply it on more variables it didn't work. Can you please advise? I will update my question shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 df1%>%
       left_join(df2)%>%
       mutate(result=param_a/param_b)
    Joining, by = "user_id"
    # A tibble: 9 x 4
      user_id   param_a param_b    result
        <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
    1       1  123        34      3.62   
    2       1    2.3      34      0.0676 
    3       1   -9        34     -0.265  
    4       2    1        12      0.0833 
    5       2   -0.0333   12     -0.00278
    6       2    4        12      0.333  
    7       3  -41        -0.89  46.1    
    8       3  -12        -0.89  13.5    
    9       3    0.89     -0.89  -1
```